# Data for demonstrating world poverty on Mollweide projection?

Tags: data

I am overwhelmingly failing at finding data about global poverty that is any more specific than at the country level.

Because poverty has such a wide definition I am open to really anything that is an indicator, like high infant mortality or others.

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction for data more specific than the country level would be great?

Preferably it is not raster data but data I can manipulate on Arc 10.1.

Comment: What level of [administrative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_subdivision) boundary would you seek for looking at something on a global scale? 1st order? 2nd? Would you be factoring in to equate terms to orders? And raster data can be manipulated in ArcGIS, so by that statement should we assume you don't have access to Spatial Analyst?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to revise in response to the questions @ChrisW has raised in his comment, but also to explain whether/why this data needs to be in Mollweide projection which appears in the title but not body of your Question.  AS a tip the title is usually best written last to summarise your Question body.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sub national but not global http://gisweb.ciat.cgiar.org/povertymapping/

This will be the most interest I think http://harvestchoice.org/labs/harvestchoice-creates-worlds-first-sub-national-poverty-maps

This is a country level example.

1)In ArcMAP select "Add Data From ArcGIS Online"

2) In the search window that appears "global poverty" without quotes

[image: Global Poverty]

Change the projection to Mollweide using this image
[image: Cnage to Mollweide]

Then hit okay to any warning that appear

this is how it looks.
[image]